# Redux store changes connected component props without corresponding action being dispatched

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a very weird issue, I have redux store and a react component connected to it with connect() function. I am storing a list of user roles coming from my backend in redux. For this I have two different reducers, userRoleReducer and initialUserRolesReducer. I use the first one to handle changes into the roles in the UI before applying the changes with an API call, and the second one is being used to have the initial roles stored separately after backend responses. The issue I am having, is that both of the reducers are changing, even though only the first one is actually being updated by dispatching an action (Sorry if my use of terms is incorrect). Below are the reducers and action dispatchers.

Reducers:

```
export function userRolesForUsersRequestSuccess(state = {userRoles: []}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
  case 'USER_ROLES_FOR_USERS_REQUEST_SUCCESS':
    return action.userRoleDataForUsers;
  default:
    return state;
  }
}

export function initialUserRolesForUsersRequestSuccess(state = {userRoles: []}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'INITIAL_USER_ROLES_FOR_USERS_REQUEST_SUCCESS':
    return action.initialUserRoleData;
  default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

These are the action dispatchers, the first one is called from the connected component, and and after backend response. The second one is called only after the backend response.

```
export function setUserRolesForUsersRequestSuccess(userRoleDataForUsers) {
  return {
    type: 'USER_ROLES_FOR_USERS_REQUEST_SUCCESS',
    userRoleDataForUsers
  };
}

export function setInitialUserRolesForUsersRequestSuccess(initialUserRoleData) {
  return {
    type: 'INITIAL_USER_ROLES_FOR_USERS_REQUEST_SUCCESS',
    initialUserRoleData
  };
}
```

I haven't found anything similar to this from anywhere, so I guess this isn't a common problem, and that's why a good guess is that the issue is in my code. But every other reducer I use are working just fine, and believe me, I have tried to change and check everything I can to make these two work normally as well.

Any help is wanted to track the issue down!

EDIT: The code I use to create the store, not sure if it helps.

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './rootReducer';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

const composeEnhancers = typeof window === 'object' && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({}) : compose;

const history = createHistory();
const middleware = routerMiddleware(history);
const initialState = {};
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(middleware, thunk))
  );
```

EDIT 2. rootReducer.js file, reducers are combined here.

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';
import {
  userRoleForMeRequestSuccess,
  userRolesForUsersRequestSuccess,
  userRoleRequestPending,
  userPermissionChangeGetResponseMessage,
  initialUserRolesForUsersRequestSuccess } from './Common/userRoleReducer';
const appReducer = combineReducers({
  userRoleForMeRequestSuccess,
  userRolesForUsersRequestSuccess,
  userRoleRequestPending,
  userPermissionChangeGetResponseMessage,
  initialUserRolesForUsersRequestSuccess,
  router: routerReducer
});

const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === LOGIN_LOGOUT_REQUEST_SUCCESS) {
    state = undefined;
  }
  return appReducer(state, action);
};

export default rootReducer;
```

EDIT 3. After I dug more deeply into this problem, I made an observation that if I just pass completely different data for the first reducer, its data stays intact and doesn't change when the other one changes. So could there be some kind of issue in passing exactly the same data as the first new state after the reducers initial state, and that mixes the reducers somehow to always mirror each other?

Comment: hey, can we see how you configure your store? It looks like they might be using the same "spot" in the store. Therefore if one updates, your getter methods will get the new data. Not sure if I'm clear...

Comment: Just to make sure, so your problem is that both reducers are applied one after the other?

Comment: I mean I dispatch the other one, and data for both of them changes. What configurations I should share? Do you mean the stuff I have in my root level app.jsx file where the store is created, or something else perhaps?

Comment: I see you are using Redux DevTools. What do you see in the 'diff' tab ? One action dispatched and 2 store values being updated ?

Comment: That's exactly what's happening. And actually one other reducer also concerned about these roles is changing as well, and that reducer is  defined in completely other file. So three reducers are updating and only one should be.

Comment: I don't what to say.. please check all files properly.. definitely something wrong with your code. Check if you have assigned reducers correctly in the `rootReducer` file. You are using `combineReducers` right ?

Comment: I don't know what to check anymore, I have gone through all files using this code and everything seems to be correct.. The only place I could think of where some mistake could happen is the connected component, but I only map the reducer as a prop for that component there, nothing is changed there.

Comment: Yes please share your store configuration, where you combine all your reducers

Comment: Ok now please share the file rootReducer @MirkoFlyktman

Comment: Honestly I don't see what's wrong. Did you try to log/debug the action type at the reducers level? See what's being passed?

Comment: Yeah being doing that also, it receives the changed state and passes it down when the other action is dispatched. I mean when I console.log the default case, at first everything is fine, then suddenly it starts to get data that the other reducer should get only. I don't know if I explain that very well. Also the correct action dispatcher is not the one responsible for the changed data.

Comment: Provide a minimal working sandbox reproducing the error if you can. That's the only way we can debug the code.

Comment: I don't think I have the time for it now, maybe tomorrow. But thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Hope you'll fix it before that!

Comment: Have you tried logging something to the console from both the actions to figure whether both the actions are firing? If you have tried and find one of the consoles are not appearing then you are mutating the object somewhere and so it get's changes everywhere.

Comment: I have logged them, and I have confirmed that the other object doesn't get called ever after the initial call when I get the data from the backend, still it changes.

Comment: I don't know if I got an actual solution for this issue, but at least I managed to work around this problem. I had to change the other reducers object structure, so that it is completely different from the other reducer, even though the object is derived from the same data. So my guess is that the reducers were mixed because they had the same exact object structure and data initially, nothing else explains it for me.